# Is there a good way (or module) to modify or append data into xml file in Android?

Tags: android, xml

The situation like this, I had create a xml file in ***XmlPullParser*** way:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<users>
    <user id="1">
        <name>ABC</name>
        <password>abc</password>
    </user>
    <user id="2">
        <name>DEF</name>
        <password>def</password>
    </user>
</users>
```

And now, I want to modify or append data into this xml file, except to create a new xml file (or clean the original data and import the new data), is there a good way to do this based on the original file?

Comment: Also please consider post an ideal output xml document...

Comment: Well, @vtd-xml-author thank you so much. You had really suggested me a good way to solve the problem, and now I'm been reading the PDF and the Docs./APIS about the VTD-XML. Thanks again.